# Chrome devTools no longer displaying my windows size

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, viewport

Chrome development tools is no longer showing me the pixel dimensions of my viewport/browser window. I'm using windows. What setting did I accidentally toggle and how do I get it to display this again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it’s a bug, which was fixed: [crbug.com/582421](https://crbug.com/582421)

If you [switch channels to beta or dev or canary](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel), you can enjoy these bugs before they make stable, and you can also enjoy the fixes sooner.

Comment: thanks that worked, but so annoying that I had to reinstall chrome (which is not your fault). I want to shake my fist at google for making me waste an hour on this!  What a nuisance, argh!